# GAE apps in China, *.appspot.com hosted domain

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall

I have read that subdomain for appspot.com can't be accessed in China because it is block by GreatFireWall of China. How about if your app is hosted in other domain e.g. http://example.com, will it be accessible?

I tested at http://viewdns.info/chinesefirewall and http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org, the result is that the domain can be accessed but not our appspot.com subdomain. Will it encounter some trouble or I missed something while testing.

What are other option on this?

Comment: How about using an VPN to be able to test it yourself and not really on testers/mixed answer? Maybe this [list of VPN providers](http://www.bestvpnservice.com/blog/best-chinese-ip-vpn/) helps.

Answer (score 4):

We actually tested that as well and indeed when you're accessing it through the `*.appspot.com` domain it's blocked, but not when it's hosted on it's own domain.

- Khan Academy is [built entirely on Google App Engine](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/cloud.google.com/en//files/KhanAcademy.pdf) and it works nicely, so I don't think that you will have any problems with your own domain. Unless of course the *great firewall of China* will block you explicitly.
- I worked for [Remby.com](http://www.remby.com), it is built entirely on GAE and we didn't do anything special for China. From the links above it looks like it works.
- [TheSmallestCreature.com](http://thesmallestcreature.com) is also something that I created and it works.

Comment: So once GAE app is linked to a domain e.g. `example.com`, it can be accessed directly in China? No further configuration?

Comment: according to http://code.google.com/p/khanacademy/issues/detail?id=1442, Khan Academy can't be accessed in China.

Comment: Khan Academy partnered with renren in China http://www.khanacademy.org/about/blog/post/14224348732/khan-academy-teaming-up-with-renren-to-bring-free

Comment: @JRGalia I updated my answer with few more GAE apps that I know for sure that running on GAE

Comment: Thanks @Lipis, how do you verify that Remby.com works in China?

Comment: @JRGalia through the links :) I could verify these sites from within China.. But not today.. I will update my answer..

Comment: Any update on this would be appreciated! greatfirewallofchina.org shows me green for my naked domain (`example.com`) and red for `www.example.com` - I'm not sure what do make out of this.

Comment: The link for the PDF was invalid.  Here's the updated link:  https://cloud.google.com/files/KhanAcademy.pdf

Comment: I am in China right now, and I can confirm that `remby.com` and `thesmallestcreature.com` are accessible.

Answer (score 3):

No, even if you use Google's custom domain for GAE app, it will NOT be accessible in China.

You need a reverse-proxy to make it work.

Search Google App Engine group archive, there are quite a few discussions and answers there.